# devicePixelRatio broken in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, qt5, scale, dpi

I try to paint a DPI-aware widget in PyQt. For this I try to get the scaling factor, which I want to multiply with custom margins for example.

Here's what I tried:

```
self.window().devicePixelRatioF()
QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().devicePixelRatio()
```

Both return `1.0`, regardless of the actual scaling factor in windows, which *does take effect* for the Qt Application. Everything is scaled correctly, I just don't know where to get the multiplicator from.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

For someone who has the same issue, the following workaround did it for me:

```
scaling = self.logicalDpiX() / 96.0  # self is of QWidget
```

Now `scaling` has the exact Windows scaling factor. `1.0`, `1.25` ...

Since this seems like a bit of a hack though, I do not consider the question answered.